# How to get multiple substrings from a string without spaces from a word list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, encoding, while-loop

I would like to 'decode' a coded message. Each letter is coded with a unique 5/6/7/8 long 'word'. I have a dictionary of these codes ( 'a' : 'qwert',...). I tried to decode the message like this:

```py
#example dictionary
d={'a': '00101', 'b': '10001011', 'c': '01100', 'd': '1111110', 'e': '01001', 'f': '010000', 'g': '1100100', 'h': '00010010', 'i': '0000000', 'j': '1101010', 'k': '110001', 'l': '101010', 'm': '10010', 'n': '100001', 'o': '111101', 'p': '11100111', 'q': '011110', 'r': '010001', 's': '1110010', 't': '1110011', 'u': '111000', 'v': '11100', 'w': '00110101', 'x': '011111', 'y': '0111100', 'z': '0111000', ' ': '11101011', '!': '00111101', ',': '11111', '-': '000100', '.': '0110111', ':': '11010', '?': '10110110', ';': '00000101', '0': '10001', '1': '000101', '2': '101011', '3': '11011001', '4': '10010111', '5': '1011000', '6': '0100000', '7': '000001', '8': '10111010', '9': '001110'}
#coded word
coded = '0001001001001101010101010111101' #coded and d is the input, 'hello' is the expected output


def get_key(v):
    for key, value in d.items():
         if v == value:
            return key
 
    return None
 
def decode(text):
    l = []
    while len(text)> 0:
        for i in range(5,9):
            if get_key(text[0:i]) != None:
                l.append(get_key(text[0:i]))
                text = text[i:]
        
    return ''.join(str(i) for i in l)

inverse = {v:k for k,v in d.items()}

def decode(text):
    l = []
    while len(text)> 0:
        for i in range(5,9):
            if text[0:i] == inverse.keys():
                l.append(inverse.value())
                text = text[i:]
        
    return ''.join(str(i) for i in l)
```

But my code is not working. It takes quite a long time to run this code and I think that it gives back wrong letters as well. I am not sure how to correct it. Could you help me fix my code?

Comment: can you please edit the question and add the input and expected output?

Comment: Can you provide example of input and expected output ?

Comment: Your `get_key` does a linear scan over the dictionary for every lookup. It would be much more efficient to once and for all invert the dictionary (e.g. `inverse = {v:k for k,v in d.items()}`) than to repeatedly do this. Also -- don't name a dictionary `dict` since that is the name of a built-in.

Comment: Right now you are iterating through the whole dictionary for every single letter. You should first write some code to inverse your dict so you can do a single lookup per letter.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you for your help! Did you mean it like this? (I edited my question) I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: Why are you not listening to the comments which ask for input and expected output?

Comment: @fourelements sorted...

Comment: @VedankPande I edited my question.

Comment: @jossefaz I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

I approached this differently to you and there is plenty of headroom for optimisations here.  The key is this function which will return a list of indexes of substrings:

```
# function to get all the indexes of a word in a string of words
def all_word_indexes(string, substring):
    x = [len(i) for i in string.split(substring)[:-1]]
    return [sum(x[:i+1]) + i*len(substring) for i in range(len(x))]
```

The rest was pretty straightforward and looks like this:

- Obtain the list of words from the dictionary of words
- Iterate through the list finding each examples index
- Iterate within the "found" list to create a list of tuples with index of word and the actual word
- Sort these by index number as they are current in the original dictionary order to get the correct order of the letters
- Iterate over this list matching it to the reversed key, value -> value, key dictionary

Here:

```
secret_dict = {
    'a':'nation',
    'b':'variation',
    'c':'investment',
    'd':'exam',
    'e':'patience',
    'f':'inspection',
    'g':'significance',
    'h':'recipe',
    'i':'consequence',
    'j':'speaker',
    'k':'historian',
    'l':'leadership',
    'm':'meaning',
    'n':'marriage',
    'o':'month',
    'p':'loss',
    'q':'volume',
    'r':'environment',
    's':'cheek',
    't':'database',
    'u':'country',
    'v':'teacher',
    'w':'bonus',
    'x':'football',
    'y':'grocery',
    'z':'income',
    ' ':'banana'
}

# create words list from the the values of the dictionary
my_words_list = list(secret_dict.values())

# switch the values to keys and vice versa
secret_dict_reversed = dict((v,k) for k,v in secret_dict.items()) # reverse the dictionary to be value -> key

# coded phrase is hello world
coded_word = ['recipe', 'patience', 'leadership', 'leadership', 'month', 'banana', 'bonus', 'month', 'environment', 'leadership', 'exam'] # list of words, if you have a string then split it with mystring.split()
decoded_word = ''

coded_string = 'recipepatienceleadershipleadershipmonthbananabonusmonthenvironmentleadershipexam'

results = []

# function to get all the indexes of a word in a string of words
def all_word_indexes(string, substring):
    x = [len(i) for i in string.split(substring)[:-1]]
    return [sum(x[:i+1]) + i*len(substring) for i in range(len(x))]

# iterate through each word in the list
for word in my_words_list:
    word_indexes = all_word_indexes(coded_string, word)
    if len(word_indexes) > 0:
        for idx in word_indexes:
            # returns a list of tuples with word and their index or indexes
            results.append((idx, word))

# sort these results
sorted_results = list(sorted(results, key=lambda elem: elem[0]))
sorted_word_results = [x[1] for x in sorted_results]

# traverse the words to get the letters
for word in sorted_word_results:
    letter = secret_dict_reversed[word]
    decoded_word = decoded_word + letter

print(decoded_word)
# hello world
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem is that I have a codedmessage like: 'recipepatienceleadershipmonthbanana....' so I do not know the endings of each word.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately no, I think the problem is that in my case there are values in the dictionary which written after each other can make up a new value. For exampe: 'surfaces' +'unnatural,' -> 'sun'.

Comment: I edited my question. It is not for homework but for myself. I am interested in the solution.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the purpose of Stackoverflow.  It's not for people to post work into and expect people to do it for you.  The code outlined above functions per what you asked for in your original question and should have been marked as correct.  If you have a further question you should ask it and reference this question in it, not edit the question so a user looking for an answer sees something different.